# f-test for two models in R

Tags: r, model

I would like to compare two models using f-test fitting my data. For each model I performed Monte-Carlo simulation that provided statistical estimation for each model parameter and rms fit error. I would like to use f-test in R to determine which model is preferable.

Answer (score 5):

Best to use the anova function.

```
anova(modle1, model2)
```

This preforms a model f test.